# Losi iPhone 5 and device is turned off and hence can not locate using Find my Phone app

Tags: iphone

I lost my iphone 5. Within 30 minutes, I log onto my PC to find my phone. However it shows that all devices are off. I have put it in lost mode but have not erased my phone as I know he / hse may be able to operate without my password. Can you let me know if I am at risk by not erasing the iphone and will he bve able to crack my password (whcih I believe very very difficult)
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I lost my iPhone5 few months ago in August 2013. I think I had pass code setup but not iCloud (so there was no way to remote erase or to find it). The next thing I did was called the customer  service (mine was T-Mobile) and they temporarily suspended my line. I immediately changed all my passwords. I never got my brand new iPhone 5. I would suggest erasing the phone and/or if possible changing all the passwords you could remember ASAP.